# Detect subscription state Unity IAP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I want to get the subscription state in my Unity3D project (I'm using Unity IAP), so if the subscription has ended or cancelled I could just remove the exclusive subscription rewards.
I made this pseudocode so you can have an idea of it:

```
if (Subscription.HasEnded || Subscription.IsCancelled)
{
RemoveRewards();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the state of the subscription through the [Subscription Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPSubscriptionProducts.html) class.